# What is being displayed on Insights -> Users -> User Trends

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I would love to have an API call return the exact same data that is being displayed in the User Trends graph for Daily New Users on the Insights page under users.  I can't figure out which metric is being displayed since the obvious choices (either application_installation_adds or application_installation_adds_unique) return values that don't match that graph at all.  Please let me know if it's possible to see where the data for that graph is getting generated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference in statistics between the two sources?

Comment: Over the past week, the difference has ranged from -25% to 275%, so basically either the numbers I'm getting from the API are completely unreliable or they're reporting on a different stat and I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of [Platform Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights) there's a little selector in the corner of most of the charts with some options, one of which is will show you the API call used to generate that chart (though you'll need to use your own access token).

The API calls are all documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/app_insights

Here's an example showing in the frontend and the corresponding API call for the Active Login Users metric:

[image: Platform Insights Graph]

'API Examples' opens this dialog:
[image: Screenshot of API Examples]

For New users specifically, the current name of the metric in the [App Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/app_insights) is called `initial_permission_grants`

Example call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<APP ID>/app_insights?metric_key=initial_permission_grants
```

Example response [partial]:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-12T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-13T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-14T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-15T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "1"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-16T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-17T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-18T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Corresponding graph from Insights at the time the API call was made: 
[image]